# Expected ì)ì Error

Tags: ios

Xcode send me an error of Expected ')' in my AppDelegate.m file and I don't understand the problem. Somebody can help me?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{    
    NSArray *pippoInfos = [AwosDatabase database].pippoInfos;
    for (PippoInfo *info in pippoInfos) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%d: %@, %@, %@, %@" info.id, info.gigio, info.gigi, info.cip, info.ciop);
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: is that fragment all you have in AppDelegate.m? Is the line pointed by the error inside that fragment? Just to be sure...

Comment: Yes the line point to this fragment

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues in your code:

1. You omitted the closing bracket at the end of your method - but I am guessing that only happened because you did not quote the entire method.
2. You omitted the first comma in your `NSLog` line. Note that the formatting string and its parameters need to be separated using a comma.